# Format datetime in the app fetched from firestore in flutter

Tags: flutter

i am storing dateTime to the firestore by using

> DateTime.now()

but it save a long integer number like this 1609439399000

how do i format it into dd-mm-yy/hours:min

Answer (score 0):

Can you try using [`formatDate()`](https://pub.dev/packages/date_format)?

```
formatDate(DateTime.now(), [dd, '-', mm, '-', yyyy, '/', HH, ':', nn])
```

Or also you can do it as

```
final dateFormat = new DateFormat('dd-MM-yyyy/hh:mm');
print(dateFormat.format(new DateTime.fromMillisecondsSinceEpoch(DateTime.now()*1000)));
```

Comment: but i want to format the int digit while fetching, not the DateTime.now()

Comment: Instead of DateTime.now() use your int digit, I guess without the *1000 because it is already a milissecond otherwise put it.

Comment: @user11482692 Have you solved this? In order to help other people if this helped you feel free to upvote and mark this as a correct answer. Thanks :)